# Close a window without waiting for NotificationCenter post to complete Cocoa Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

Just before calling `self.window?.close()` I am posting a notification with `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("frameCaptured"), object: nil)`. The Notification's selector may take some time to complete. So I want to close the window even if the selector is not complete. Is this possible or I should approach this another way?

Comment: You can start Timer to execute after 3 or 5 sec for `self.window?.close()` if selector takes more time.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `close()` must be running on the main thread, all you need to do is queue a block to post the notification in the immediate future:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("MyNotification"), object: self);
    }
    self.window?.close()
```

The notification code will execute on some future main loop. It can't start until all of the code on the current main loop has finished, but will run as soon as all pending main loop events have caught up, which in all likelihood is immediately afterward.